# what can be wrong with my fdisk -l output?

Tags: fstab

I have reinstalled Ubuntu 5 times already and I can't find what is wrong

I messed with `/etc/fstab` and seems I don't have swap space

Can some one help me and tell if this is a healthy `fdisk -l`, and if not what I should do?

```
Disk /dev/sda: 20.4 GB, 20416757760 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2482 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0000675f

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1        2483    19936256    7  HPFS/NTFS

Disk /dev/sdb: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xafe6fd0f

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1          13      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sdb2   *          13        5839    46793727+   7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sdb3           15808       19457    29312000    7  HPFS/NTFS
Partition 3 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sdb4            5839       15807    80071552+   5  Extended
/dev/sdb5            6165       15517    75123712   83  Linux
/dev/sdb6           15518       15807     2329393+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb7            5839        6165     2618368   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/dm-0: 2385 MB, 2385298944 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 289 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x6afd02f5

Disk /dev/dm-0 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/dm-1: 2681 MB, 2681208832 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 325 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x4438c22c

Disk /dev/dm-1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Output of `ls /dev/mapper`:

```
control  cryptswap1  cryptswap2
```

Sometimes, my computer drops to an initramfs shell on boot or becomes very slow. I think it's because there is something wrong with my swap space.

This is my fstab file:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc    /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=f78f1d1f-82e3-48bd-b3e5-03fd8b75dfcc /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdb6 during installation
#UUID=a3c19631-c3ed-44b2-b409-7ed31fd3d7aa none            swap    sw             0       0
# swap was on /dev/sdb7 during installation
#UUID=5e8beccd-8dbb-431b-aa65-c1f073b30b10 none            swap    sw             0       0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap2 none swap sw 0 0
```

this is outpost of mount.

```
/dev/sdb5 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro,commit=0)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
n    one on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
none on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
none on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /var/run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
none on /var/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
/home/lerry/.Private on /home/lerry/Private type ecryptfs (ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs,ecryptfs_sig=bbdcf1ee6db39142,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=aab58941a7c801da)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/lerry/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=lerry)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you have dm-N devices there.  Post the output of `ls /dev/mapper`

Comment: Could you provide the output of `mount`? Add it to your question, do not post it as answer.

Answer (score 3):

I've converted that output to an image:

[image: graphical representation]

At first, I thought there was something wrong. Looking closer, I noticed that you've just removed some partitions from the middle of the disk and created new ones: the extended partition holding the swap, the root partition and another swap (in that order). You do not need two swaps, I suggest:

- remove one swap (sdb7)
- expand the root partition (sdb5) with the space from the removed swap
- shrink the root partition on the right
- expand the swap (sdb6)
  To do this, boot into a LiveCD and start the Disk Utility.

The output is OK, there is nothing wrong with it except for a strange partitioning order which is caused by removing / creating partitions. The `sdb4` partition is a special one, the extended partition. All partitions with a number greater than 4 are logical partitions inside the extended partition. Partitions 1-3 are primary partitions.

Th next time, do not mess that much with the system configuration files without making a backup of those.

Regarding your fstab file, you don't have an encrypted root system, let alone a swap. I've not the slightest clue how you got one (perhaps a remaining from a previous install?). So you'd better replace the last two lines with:

```
/dev/sdb7 none swap sw 0 0
/dev/sdb6 none swap sw 0 0
```

The floppy one looks suspicious too, why would you automatically mount a floppy? I would remove it. (or comment it out)